# draw a shape with c# in silverlight in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-5.0, windows-mobile-6.5

i found a link in msdn to draw a shape in .XAML file, but how to do the same with c#, drawing a shape with c# in wp7 in silverlight without use xna?

Comment: please any suggestion will be a great help, i really need it, thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008895/drawing-things-on-a-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-1-getting-started-and-line-shape will help you to draw shapes using C#.

Your XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ContentPanelCanvas" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Line X1="10" Y1="100" X2="150" Y2="100" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="5"/>
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
Line line = new Line();
line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
line.StrokeThickness = 15;

Point point1 = new Point();
point1.X = 10.0;
point1.Y = 100.0;

Point point2 = new Point();
point2.X = 150.0;
point2.Y = 100.0;

line.X1 = point1.X;
line.Y1 = point1.Y;
line.X2 = point2.X;
line.Y2 = point2.Y;

this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

Comment: you're welcome souphia and let me know if you need some help regarding drawing images as I'm aslo working with the same.

Comment: i really thank you,i want to draw a series of ellipses with a points loop,i succeed to draw one with geometryGroup,but i couldn't draw more than one,and i noted that every time will draw in the same location,of course i changed the center

Comment: have you looked at this http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/11/drawing-shapes-silverlight.html

Comment: it's good but, it'll be better to accept float points as in geometry classes,but except the msdn explains can you suggest any link to explain geometry useings

Comment: I think you need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614589/how-to-design-shape-class, http://www.functionx.com/csharp3/math/Lesson20.htm and this http://books.google.be/books?id=iF7z1-S9haoC&lpg=PA112&ots=RwQiVTQQQw&dq=silverlight%20windows%20phone%207%20float%20ellipse&hl=nl&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: please DotNetter can you give me an e-mali  to connect,